# how to write custom .spec.ts file in a angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to make a custom .spec.ts file in my angular application which can test all the methods of components.ts files and service.ts file & i want to test the non-value returning methods also.

I created a custom spec.ts file for testing my application, but those test are failed

```
it('should handle', () => { 
    expect(component.Id).toBe(null);
    component.isKeyUp();
    expect(component.show).toBe(true);
  });
```

It is showing Id not found in my custom.spec.ts file ,but in that component.spec.ts file it run perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `detectChanges()` method in `component` after `isKeyUp()` has been invoked.

```ts
it('should handle', () => { 
    expect(component.Id).toBe(null);
    component.isKeyUp();
    component.detectChanges();
    expect(component.show).toBe(true);
  });
```